# How to change the viewport settings through Adobe CQ?

Tags: adobe, viewport, head, aem

I am working on a site using Adobe CQ and somewhere CQ is automatically adding:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

right after the opening head tag. Does anyone know where I can change this is in Adobe CQ so I can get this site displaying correctly for the iPad? Maybe there is a way to override any other viewport settings found on a page? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default head script for the mobile page in CQ5.5 can be found at `libs/wcm/mobile/components/page/head.jsp`

The default head script for the web page in CQ5.5 can be found at `/libs/foundation/components/page/head.jsp`

You can override the foundation head.jsp by creating a resource using this path: `/apps/<site-id>/components/page/base/head.jsp`. Any content in this resource will override content in default(libs/) head.jsp.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is added via js in `/libs/cq/touch/widgets/source/jquerymobile/jquery.mobile.js`, search for `metaViewportContent` string.

I haven't found yet how to change it in proper way, though.